# Can I use 5e cleric spells in D&D?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric

I'm playing an improvised D&D campaign.  I use spells for cleric from the Cleric spell list in the *Starter set Rulebook* and there are so few spells.

For example I am missing *purify food and drink* spell, and lots of other important ones,  In the book I have 5 cantrips.  When I search the web for cleric spells I get so much more than in the rulebook.

What spell list should I use *starter set* spell list or *internet* spell list?

Comment: What exactly is the "internet spell list" you are referring to? Are you wondering about compatibility issues?

Comment: Which starter set are you using? For which edition of D&D?

Comment: Have you down loaded the [Basic Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PlayerBasicRulesV03.pdf) or the[SRD_5.1](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf) from Wizards of the Coast web site?  These are free to use and have more spells than the starter set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Ask your DM.

The DM decides what sources are allowed in the campaign and what sources are not.  When you find some list of spells somewhere which you would like to use, show it to your DM.

- If DM says it's OK, you can use them.
- If DM says no, you can't.

#### What "internet spells?"

You didn't say which "internet spell list" you mean.  There is a lot of "home-brewed" D&D content flying around the internet.  This is content which players designed themselves.

While there are some really great and well thought out ideas among home-brewed content, you will often find material which is badly balanced, only balanced within the context of the house rules of the group which made it up, or does not fit together well with other content from other sources.

Also be wary of using content designed for other editions of D&D. There were considerable rule changes between the editions which greatly affected game balance.  That means that some content is hard to convert from one edition to the other.

When your group is not very experienced with the D&D rules yet, then you might not yet have the experience to judge what's balanced and what isn't.  You are better off sticking to the spells:

1. Found in any official material published by WotC
2. That apply to the edition of D&D you are playing.

Comment: @Patta Philipp has considered the case of trying to use spells from a different edition.

Comment: Sorry, I am blind.

Comment: I wonder why 4 people downvoted this answer even though only one person wrote a comment with constructive criticism (which they deleted after realizing they misread the answer).

Comment: Philipp I too am puzzled, it may be that DV's came from answering a question that was unclear to start with and then got put on hold ... if and when clarification arrives about the question, I think you'll need to edit this again since you ended up guessing about what spell list @Spellcaster was asking about.  When that is confirmed some of what you wrote won't be needed.

Comment: Also, I edited your answer for format/organization.   Please review and make sure it's consistent with what you wished to say.

Comment: Essentially what Korvin said. I downvoted because you answered an unclear question, did so in a way which looks authoritative (but can't be, because the question is really unclear), and by answering, discouraged the asker from clarifying. Also, I think the first part of your answer is misleading, even if true.